# Finding "minimal" union of sets containing all elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a list of elements, with each element belonging to a number of sets . For example:

Jack -  Developer, Footballer, Video gamer
John -  Carpenter, historian, footballer
Jim  -  Professor, politician, Man
Jill -  Professor, Footballer

I want to find the "minimal" union of sets (Developer, Footballer, etc.) that will contain all elements (Jack, John, Jim, Jill).

A trivial solution is union of all sets. That is correct, but is not minimal (in terms of number of sets in the union) in the general case.

Please note that I am interested in the general case, not just in the example provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is known as [set cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem). It is NP-hard, so it is conjectured that there is no efficient algorithm in the general case. However, there are various heuristics and approximation algorithms, and even exact algorithms which are better than exhaustive search.

Comment: Is there any math library that I could use in python/any other programming language that implements such an algorithm? I'm currently using union of all sets as a stopgap measure, but if there is a simple library it would help..

Comment: note that being strictly "minimal" is not absolutely necessary in my use case. I would be happy to get a significantly smaller solution (in terms of number of sets) than the union of all sets.